# How to go into a class in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is how my current file looks. Is there a command or shortcut to go to the actual Java file of crud repository? (I wanna see what that class looks like) I tried hovering over it 
but crud repository wasn't clickable.

[image]

Comment: Please post code and not images.

Comment: Now for the answer. It actually depends. If you have the source file, you can, else you'll not be able to view it.

Comment: Isn't the image the same as the code? I didn't want to type it all out

Comment: No. Imagine that we want to copy-paste your code.

Comment: Alright i got it. My bad. Won't happen again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by  holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and clicking on it.

<sub>Seems you are just starting with Eclipse IDE. [Have a look](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm).</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I never had to use shortcuts like this. I still have a long way to go

Comment: @committedandroider N.P. Good luck. Rome was not built in a day :)

Comment: How come I see "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found." When I hover over it. When I hold Ctrl and click it say no source found. I am clicking on class hello extends HttpServlet

Answer (score 2):

- Hold Ctrl and Click on the Class Name
- If you get error as "Source not found"
- Use "Attach Source" button to add the source zip or folder.

Comment: i got to it fine. Is attach source necessary?

Comment: If you got it, then no need :)

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I even asked that.... Only attach source if you get a source not found error.

Answer (score 1):

*ctrl-click* on the name, you need the sorce of the file or you will see a *decompiled* version of the class

for open source project, or where you can get sources, you can add the jar of the sources or a folder to the library definition

Comment: decompiled version? can you elaborate on that? I know compile is just to turn jar file to computer readable byte format

Comment: when the editor does not have accces to the source it shows a text obtained by inspecting the class files, and rendering it in human-readable format like:

//  (version 1.7 : 51.0, super bit)
public class java.lang.Exception extends java.lang.Throwable {
  
  // Field descriptor #7 J
  static final long serialVersionUID = -3387516993124229948L;
  
  // Method descriptor #1 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  public Exception();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokespecial java.lang.Throwable() [22]
    4  return
etc...

Comment: so basically a way of throwing an exception, telling the user that the class doesn't exist?

Comment: not really, it is the whole class decompiled, what you saw was referring to an exception since I did click no the java.lang.Exception class from JDK, and having no source it did show that (better formatted in Eclipse), just try it on any class and you'll see